# Application Loader support for Apple ID in multiple teams

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a simple problem. My developer account is attached to a number of different 'teams'; I have various clients who each have their own Apple Developer account and so they add me to their team. Normal operation is fine - when I login to the Apple Developer Centre, I get to choose which team I'm logging in to.

The problem I've uncovered today is that the Application Loader application (which is what is used to upload an app to iTunes Connect for review) doesn't seem to support the team concept;

- My client has created his app under his account and the app is now in 'waiting to upload' state (he sent me a screenshot, so I'm sure of this)
- Yet when I run the application loader, I see 'no eligible applications found'

To be clear, the problem is not that I don't know how to use Application Loader with multiple Apple IDs (which is a common question). The problem is how to use Application Loader with a single Apple ID that is attached to multiple Developer accounts.

Any help/ suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Application Loader already support multiple teams, but I still run into the same issue today. That's because the version of Application Loader provided on iTunes connect is 3.0, which don't support multiple teams.

I am not sure what's the lowest version which supports multiple team login, but I've test it on version 3.4, and it works.

You can find the latest Application Loader in Xcode:

Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader
[Find application loader in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkYV4.png)

And now you should be able to login with you account which attached to multiple teams. Let's check the version of Application Loader.
[Version of Application Loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1kIM.png)

To change your developer team, click the team selector button on left top.
[Select your team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pZoK.png)

The key point is to open Application Loader with Xcode, do not use the one download from iTunesconnect.

Hope this answer is help to people who experience the same issue.

Hubert

Answer (score 0):

Try to use organizer after Build and Archive application instead of using Application loader. When you build and archive it will open organizer and you will able to upload app. I didn't face this problem but I think it should work. Can you just give it a try once ? (window --> Organizer)

Comment: Thanks Deeps, will have a go. Is this an Xcode 4 feature or is it available in Xcode 3 as well?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I think it should there in xCode 3 too.

Comment: Having a similar problem. It fails in both Application Loader and Xcode organizer. :(

Comment: But some of us hate xcode, because it's giant, buggy, clunky, and slow and would like to deploy our flutter apps with out having to open it!  If you're like me, just pin xcode's app loader to your bar and viola you're free.  Until you need platform code or to write a native plug in.